# VB.net For Loop to capture data from multiple controls (CheckBoxList Items)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, web-controls

I have two CheckBoxList controls (`chkListVideoMedia` and `chkListAudioMedia`) on my page that I want to capture information from and insert the records into the database. I have it working for one of the controls, I just need help modifying my code below to include the second CBL

```
Dim values As New ArrayList()
For counter As Integer = 0 To chkListVideoMedia.Items.Count - 1
    If chkListVideoMedia.Items(counter).Selected Then
        MyTextBox.Text = chkListVideoMedia.Items(counter).Value
        values.Add(newId)
    End If
Next
If values.Count > 0 Then
  For item As Integer = 0 To values.Count - 1
    If item = 0 Then
      MyMedia1.Text = values(item).ToString
    End If
    If item = 1 Then
      MyMedia2.Text = values(item).ToString
    End If
    If item = 2 Then
      MyMedia3.Text = values(item).ToString
    End If
    If item = 3 Then
      MyMedia4.Text = values(item).ToString
    End If
  Next
End If
```

Thanks,
James

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - you need help adding the code for the second control in what way?  Are you trying to do it all in one loop?  I don't think you can.

Comment: Are you wanting to put them in the same ArrayList?

Comment: @Tim

I have one check box list for Videos files and one for Audio files, The user will check 2 from video and 2 from audio for example. When they click submit, the Selected Values of the checked items are inserted into my database. The above code works perfectly for the Video CBL, I just need to include the Audio CBL in the same record insertion. Another example is, they might only choose audio items.

Comment: @MarkHall - yes all in the one array, please see my comment above this one :)

Comment: Why not just simply repeat the code (with necessary changes) for the second CBL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which Collection has the most Items, then check to make sure that count is not greater than the maximum Items in each collection. Something like this.

```
Dim values As New ArrayList()
Dim counter As Integer
If chkListVideoMedia.Items.Count > chkListAudioMedia.Items.Count Then
    counter = chkListVideoMedia.Items.Count - 1
Else
    counter = chkListAudioMedia.Items.Count - 1
End If
For x = 0 To counter
    If Not (counter > chkListVideoMedia.Items.Count - 1) Then
        'Do your work here
    End If
    If Not (counter > chkListAudioMedia.Items.Count - 1) Then
        'Do your work here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution.  The only thing I could come up with was brute force :)